# Can I use number prefix in haskell source file name?

Tags: haskell

I tried solving programming problems with haskell.
For convenience, I used filename like `01-apple.hs`, `02-banana.hs`, `03-caramel.hs`.

But I don't know how can I use these files as modules. Module identifiers are not likely to be prefixed with numbers. Can't I use these kind of filenames?

Comment: what about symlinks?

Comment: You can stick an extra letter or two on the front. I don't think there's any real way around the need to match file names to module names.

Comment: It might make sense to expand the lexical syntax to accommodate more module names, but I doubt anyone would care enough to think it worth the trouble to implement.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr That's a detour slightly unsatisfactory, but I agree that can be one of the solutions.

Comment: @dfeuer Then you say there's no direct method to handle this and `P03Caramel.hs` would be the best compromise. I can accept that as a answer.

Comment: I wonder what's supposed to be convenient about this naming scheme, anyway.

Comment: @leftaroundabout For brevity?

Comment: Um, it would be even briefer if you just omitted the prefix numbers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot start a Haskell module with a number as modules must start with a capital letter. [(Source)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Modules#Modules)

You can have numbers in the filename as long as they are not first so `Apple01.hs` is just fine.

Haskell files themselves do not have these restrictions, GHC will have no issues compiling `01-apple.hs`.